# Ajax timeout in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, uiwebview

I'm working on an iOS app that displays a webpage through a `UIWebView`. The page contains between 20 and 40 buttons. Each one sends an ajax request to the server. It works for the most part, but the server is a desktop app and could close at any moment for any reason with no warning. With these ajax requests, there is no output displayed to the user so if the server went down, the user would have no idea. I would like to be able to be notified of an ajax timeout and then give the user the options to either try again or go back to the home screen. I can't seem to find a way to have the `UIWebView` be notified of any failed ajax requests.

At first I thought I could simply use the `webView:didFailLoadWithError:` method of the `UIWebViewDelegate`, but apparently it's not notified of failed ajax requests.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Comment: By using javascript, you can add a timeout routine to check it or jQuery ajax function also works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If when a failure occurs, there is JavaScript code that is invoked in your Ajax failure handlers that makes a location.href change then the UIWebViewDelegate  shouldStartLoadWithRequest: method will get called, giving you the chance to do something whenever there is a failure. i.e.

In the Ajax timeout handling code:

```
 window.location.href = "myscheme://AjaxFailure";
```

In your UIWebViewDelegate handling code:

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{
    NSLog(@"shouldStartLoadWithRequest: url: %@", [[request URL] absoluteString]);
    NSURL *URL = request.URL;
    if ([URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"myscheme"])
    {
     ... notify the user there was an error
```

Comment: the url never changes. The ajax requests makes a change on the server but nothing that's measurable from the client side

Comment: I think you misunderstood my reply? If in the Ajax timeout handling code you do a location.href call as I've shown above then that will notify your Objective-C code that there was an error and give you the chance to notify the user so they can try again or go back to the home screen. This is the only way you can communicate the Ajax error back to the Objective-C code that implements the UIWebView and UIWebView delegate. I made a couple of small tweaks to the description in the reply to hopefully clarify a bit better.